# 30 days of React (Day 4) pdf

Tags: javascript, css, html, reactjs

I was following the [30 days of react pdf for day 4](https://www.fullstackreact.com/30-days-of-react/day-4/) and I can't seem to get the css to render at all. I can get the text and image to show.
I tried to basically copy the the helloworld concept but I put everything in one html for now. I also tried day 4 example from github and the index.html doesn't render anything either. In so, if anyone know why, can you please help me out. Thanks in advance.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/auser/2bc34b9abf07f34f602dccd6ca855df1/raw/070d6cd5b4d4ec1a3e6892d43e877039a91a9108/timeline.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  <title>Time Line App</title>
  <!-- Script tags including React -->

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script type="text/babel">
    class App extends React.Component { render() { return (
    <div className="notificationsFrame">
      <div className="panel">
        <Header />
        <Content />
      </div>
    </div>
    ) } } class Header extends React.Component { render() { return (
    <div className="header">
      <div className="fa fa-more"></div>
      <span className="title">Timeline</span>
      <input type="text" className="searchInput" placeholder="Search ..." />
      <div className="fa fa-search searchIcon"></div>
    </div>
    ) } } class Content extends React.Component { render() { return (
    <div className="content">
      <div className="line"></div>
      {/* Timeline item */}
      <div className="item">
        <div className="avatar">
          <img alt='Doug' src="http://www.croop.cl/UI/twitter/images/doug.jpg" /> Doug
        </div>
        <span className="time">
An hour ago
</span>
        <p>Ate lunch</p>
        <div className="commentCount">
          2
        </div>
      </div>
      {/* ... */}
    </div>
    ) } } var mount = document.querySelector('#app'); ReactDOM.render(
    <App />, mount);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the errors you are getting in the browser’s dev tools?

Comment: @Victor no errors just warnings : You are using the in-browser Babel transformer. Be sure to precompile your scripts for production - https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/
u @ babel.min.js:24
f @ babel.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ babel.min.js:1

Comment: It runs for me! I am not sure what exact results you are expecting in terms of styling, but it renders. Look at [this pen](https://codepen.io/victorbarbu/pen/aEEbYd)

Comment: @Victor the css is supposed to looked like the image here: https://www.fullstackreact.com/30-days-of-react/day-4/#putting-it-all-together

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. So it just needed to add the `class = "demo"` to the `div id = "app"></div>`.

So it should like this this: `<div id="app" class="demo"></div>`. Also I had to download the css locally. Haven't got it work from the link given in the css. There was some minor css difference from the pdf image.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed most of my problems!